# max width for HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I met some problem in designing HTML and CSS. the picture that i make it on one of the divide class and the width is not full. For an example the picture is not fully fix in there and there will have some white blank in the left and right side.

```css
.background1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(background1.jpg);
  height: 80vh;
  max-width: 2250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background1">
  <h1>Description</h1>
  <h2>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Chances are that blank space is part of the image itself. Can you please include a JSFiddle?

Comment: Maybe default body margin? [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/nsxzmj5u/4/) 
Please add full CSS code you have.

Comment: As others have said, please include all the relevant code in a [**minimal,reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can actually see the problem and be able to help. However please include it as a snippet using the `<>` button on the editor tool bar rather than a fiddle - you can include a fiddle as well if you wish, but the Stack Overflow guidelines say that the question must include all the relevant information without having to visit other sites.

Comment: Is this you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/v5L3wdme/14/

Answer (score 0):

body tag has its own margin
you can do this:

```
body {
    margin :0;
}
```